# Prove that $\sin^{2n+4}(x)+\cos^{2n+4}(x) \leq \frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2^{n+1}} + \cos^2(2x)$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer and $x$ a real number. Prove that $\sin^{2n+4}(x)+\cos^{2n+4}(x) \leq \dfrac{\sin^2(2x)}{2^{n+1}} + \cos^2(2x)$.

Should I use the $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$ properties to solve this? Seeing as how we have the $2n+4$ in the exponent, we should be able to get $$\sin^{2n+4}(x)+\cos^{2n+4}(x) = \sin^{2n+2}(x)\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2n+2}(x)\cos^2(x).$$ Then I get stuck

Comment: I think the last equality should be $\sin^{2n+4}(x)+\cos^{2n+4}(x) = \sin^{2n+2}(x)\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2n+2}(x)\cos^2(x).$

Comment: Maybe induction will work?

Comment: $$\sin^{2n+4}x=\dfrac{(2\sin^2x)^{n+2}}{2^{n+2}}$$

We need $$2\sin^2{2x}+2^{n+2}\cos^22x\ge2^{n+2}(\sin^{2n+4}x+\cos^{2n+4}x)=(1-\cos2x)^{n+2}+(1+\cos2x)^{n+2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\sin x$ and $b=\cos x$.

Thus we must prove that given the conditions,

$|a| \leq 1 ,|b| \leq 1, a^{2}+b^{2}=1,$

$a^{2n+4}+b^{2n+4} \leq \frac{4a^{2}b{^2}}{2^{n+1}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$ (using our double angle rules).

Now, consider when $n=0$.

We must prove;

$a^{4}+b^{4} \leq 2a^{2}b^{2}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4} \Rightarrow 0 \leq 2a^{2}(1-a^{2})+1-4a^{2}+3a^{4}-(1-a^{2})^{2}= 2a^{2}-2a^{4}+1-4a^{2}+3a^{4}-1-a^{4}+2a^{2} \Rightarrow 0 \leq (4a^{2}-4a^{2})+(2a^{4}-2a^{4})$

which is clearly true.

Assume for some integer $k \geq 0$ that our inequality holds.

Thus,

$a^{2k+4}+b^{2k+4} \leq \frac{4a^{2}b{^2}}{2^{k+1}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$.

Then we must show that for $k+1$,

$a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq \frac{4a^{2}b{^2}}{2^{k+2}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$

We begin by noting that, since, $a^{2}+b^{2}=1$, we have,

$(a^{2k+4}+b^{2k+4})(a^{2}+b^{2}) \leq \frac{4a^{2}b{^2}}{2^{k+1}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$

$a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6}+a^{2}b^{2}b^{2k+2}+b^{2}a^{2}a^{2k+2} \leq \frac{4a^{2}b{^2}}{2^{k+1}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}. \Rightarrow a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq a^{2}b^{2}[\frac{4}{2^{k+1}}-(a^{2k+2}+b^{2k+2})]
+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$

(*)

Note that, by the AM-GM inequality, we have,

$\frac{(a^{n+1})^{2}+(b^{n+1})^{2}}{2} \geq \sqrt{(a^{n+1}b^{n+1})^{2}}=|(ab)^{n+1}| \Rightarrow (\sin^{n+1}(x))^{2}+(\cos^{n+1}(x))^{2} \geq 2|\sin(x)\cos(x)^{n+1}|=2|\frac{\sin^{n+1}(2x)}{2^{n+1}}| \geq \frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Thus,

$(a^{n+1})^{2}+(b^{n+1})^{2} \geq \frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Now, continuing from $(*)$,

$a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq a^{2}b^{2}[\frac{4}{2^{k+1}}-(a^{2k+2}+b^{2k+2})]
+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4} \Rightarrow a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq a^{2}b^{2}[\frac{4}{2^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{k}}]+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4} \Rightarrow a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq a^{2}b^{2}[\frac{1}{2^{k}}]+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4} \Rightarrow a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq \frac{4a^{2}b^{2}}{2^{k+2}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$

Thus from this last inequality we have,

$a^{2k+6}+b^{2k+6} \leq \frac{4a^{2}b^{2}}{2^{k+2}}+1-4a^{2}+4a^{4}$.

And by the inductive principle the proof is complete.